# How can I convert string to integer and access each individual char in string as integer?

Tags: java, string, integer, type-conversion

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
        int no;
        String s;
        s = "12345";
}
```

I want to convert the string `s` to an integer named `no`.
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you want to do with the individual chars? What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting String to Int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java)

Comment: I want to do multiplication of individual characters .

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do multiplication of individual characters? What is the use case?

Comment: what if the number  is 1000 digit long and you have to calculate the multiplication of each digit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy, to get your `String` as an integer use:

```
no = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

And if you wish to convert it to a char array use:

```
char[] charArray = ("" + no).toCharArray();
```

Then if you wish to get an `int` from a specific `char` you can use:

```
int x = Character.getNumericValue(charArray.charAt(0)); // or any index instead of 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure the string is parsable to integer
if so, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    try {
        results[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the parseInt() function available in Java. Your program will be--
You wanted an individual character seperately. For that the program will go something like this--

```
public class test{
public static void main(String args[]){

    String s = "12345";
    char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();

    int a[] = new int[charArray.length];

    String[] strarray = new String[charArray.length];

    for(int i=0;i<charArray.length;i++){
        strarray[i] = String.valueOf(charArray[i]);
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(strarray[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<charArray.length;i++){
        System.out.print(strarray[i]);
    }

    System.out.println();

    for(int i=0;i<charArray.length;i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]);
    }

}
```

}

Here we are storing the individual values of String into a character variable of type array. Define the length of the string array same as that of the length of the character array(Cause you have that many elements.). Store the values present in each character array into the string array. At the same time convert the string to integer using parseInt() and store it in an integer array. That's it!

Comment: I want to get individual character separately.

Comment: @Shubham. You could use % operator to get individual digit now. Or ig you actually want to play by characters, loop through the string and use Integer.parseInt there